# Rounded corners in layout with custom color on Android

Tags: java, android, rounded-corners

I've got an xml for the **shape** and **color** of my drawable :

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/light_red"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

But I would like to use this drawable as a global one, like having the corners rounded when I'm using it, but being able to change the `backgroundColor`.

But when I'm trying to change the `backgroundColor` programatically, it overrides the color like I want but it also override the rounded corners which becomes flat.

For the moment, if I want to have rounded corners with different colors, I need to create multiple XML files with only the `android:color` changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To programmatically change a color globally defined in a shape, use this:

```
findViewById(R.id.your_xml_element).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for other people coming here after, I did some research with what you gave me, this `setColorFilter` is deprecated since API 29.
I found the solution for non deprecated method (a little bit longer but working):

```java
findViewById(R.id.your_xml_element).getBackground().setColorFilter(BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(Color.BLUE, BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP));
```